# three.js canvas won't clear - particle trails

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, three.js

This code was working previously, and I haven't made any major alterations to the graphics code except for debugging this issue.

The link is live so open it up (~500kb), the problem is very evident as it immediately begins streaking particles as it auto rotates, the view does not seem to clear between frames. Previously this has worked perfectly fine.

I have tried:

1. renderer.clear() each frame (~line 623)
2. passing in {preserveDrawingBuffer: false} to the canvas renderer
   (~line 607)
3. renderer.autoClear = true (~line 608)
4. renderer.setClearColor added manually (~line 609)

Code / Demo: http://is.gd/uur42v

The most recent alterations were to add some more GUI helpers, not really directly related to the graphics engine, and the graphics code for all functional purposes seems identical to a past working copy.

A nice looking, but frustratingly unsolved example: http://is.gd/fG7k7k

Comment: Update to the current version r.63. Provide a simple, live, non-minified example to demonstrate the problem -- not your entire project.

Comment: @WestLangley - I have no doubt this is related to my project as a whole, as I say the graphics (three.js) code itself is only, what, 30 lines. A test case will nearly definitely work entirely as expected. Also only three.js & dat.gui.js are minified into 1 line each, the rest is quite well formatted. I will generate one for you though - I have nothing else to do until I can get past this.

Comment: @WestLangley - http://is.gd/Q66AoI as expected, works fairly well - though there is still 'streaking' on the edges when those areas don't need to be updated on the canvas (no changes that frame). Mostly the same concepts as the project but as I say there are many more factors and moving parts that could be responsible in the full project.

Comment: Go ahead an file a three.js bug report using your simple example. Your camera params are extreme, but that is not the issue.

Comment: Original bug updated with simpler example: http://is.gd/2DjI3Z however I am still not convinced a bug is the cause as it WAS working with nearly identical (besides formatting) graphics code. I have a feeling it has to be something really silly if anyone has any pointers even in the right direction.

Comment: See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4178#issuecomment-29952578 and see if things fix themselves.

Comment: @WestLangley - as per my notes on the case, I have tried this and updated the short example and full project above - no change unfortunately. Do you think as well that the short and the full examples show the same problem? In the short one it only happens on the edges, in the full for every particle persistently?

Comment: Please provide a live link to your updated short example.

Comment: @WestLangley - apologies - the simple example is now working. I will spend some time inferencing the differences between that and my full scale project, however that is largely what I have been doing already with the examples, without success.